# how to replace local version ascx control with current tfs version?

Tags: tfs

I ran into an issue this morning while working on a control. I made a couple changes and checked it back in and checked it back out. Everything worked fine until I used ctrl-z to many times because when I made a new change I kept getting errors in the frontend and screwed up my local copy, now I am getting a ton of errors on rebuild and I need to know how to take the version that I checked in and replace the screw up that I did on my local copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I undid all pending changes and that worked.